# Difference between Python match/case and type() command. When to use which?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the difference between the following codes and what use case exist for each. Or are they just redundant code?

Code 1 (Using match/case)

```
var = 0

match var:
     case str():
         print("string")
     case list():
         print("list")
     case float():
         print("float")
     case bool():
         print("boolean")
     case int():
         print("integer")
     case _:
         print("unknown")
```

This gives me the following output as it should

```
integer
```

Code 2 (Using type())

```
print(type(var))
```

This also gives me the same output as it should

```
<class 'int'>
```

Wondering what could be different use cases for these?

Comment: The `match/case` construct is very, very new.  Prior to that, `if/elif` chains were the only solution, using `isinstance(var,str)`.

Comment: If the type were something that is not in the list of `case` options (for example dict or tuple), then the first code would print "unknown".  But the second code would print the correct type.

Answer (score 3):

It's harder to find the similarities in your two code snippets! I'll describe each of them, though.

```py
# snippet one

match 0:
    case str():  # construct the empty string and see if it's 0
    case list():  # construct an empty list and see if it's 0
    case float():  # construct the zero float and see if it's 0
    case bool():  # construct the zero bool (false) and see if it's 0
    case int():  # construct the zero int and see if it's 0
        # it is, of course!
        print('integer')
    case _:  # if nothing else, do this
```

```py
# snippet two

print(type(0))  # print the type of 0
```

The former is a control statement -- you can do *anything* in those blocks. The latter is a statement that produces the type `int`.

Consider code like:

```py
class Command:
    def __init__(self, cmd, verbose=False):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.verbose = verbose


run_python = Command("python")
run_python_verbose = Command("python", verbose=True)

def execute_command(cmd: Command):
    match cmd:
        case Command(cmd="python"):
            print("Hey, you're running Python!")
        case Command(cmd=cmd, verbose=True):
            print(f"Running {cmd} verbosely!")
        case Command(cmd=cmd):
            print(f"Running {cmd} succinctly")

execute_command(run_python)
execute_command(run_python_verbose)
```

In both cases here you get `"Hey, you're running Python!"` because Python is matching against fields in the class, and `python` is the `cmd` field in both. You can't do that sort of pattern matching with `type` (you'd need something like `type(cmd) is Command and cmd.cmd == "python"`)

Answer (score 2):

`match` is not dynamically expandable, meaning you have to hardcode each value. There are some cases where this may be helpful, such as displaying a type or error to a user unfamiliar with programming. `type()` on the other hand, returns the base class of an instance. In your example, `0` is an instance of the builtin `int` type.

Using, `type`, takes up less space, and in addition, can be used with a dictionary to replace `match`. Since `match` and `case` are/were new to python in 3.10, they may have limited support. Many companies and production environments will still be using 3.8. If you do need to hardcode different values, instead of match, or if-elif-else, you can use a dictionary to map a key to a value:

```py
typesdict = {
   str: "string",
   int: "integer",
   # etc.
}

var = 0 # 0
vart = type(var) # int

typesdict.get(vart, default="Unknown") # returns "integer".
```

As for use cases, both `type` and `match` have more subtle and complex features, which are likely to not be needed in a simple use case such as this. `type` is more common in object-orientated programming paradigms, while `match` is used in complex control flow scenarios. Personally, I would use `type`, simply because `match` may not be supported in whichever environment you may be working.

TL;DR: Use type, to prevent hardcoding values and for support.

Answer (score 2):

Both Code 1 (**using match/case**) and Code 2 (**using type()**) are used to determine the data type of a variable. However, they have some differences in terms of their use cases and behavior.

**Code 1 (Using match/case):**

`match` is a new feature introduced in Python 3.10. It allows you to perform pattern matching on the value of an expression.
In the given code, match is used to pattern match the value of the variable var and then execute the corresponding block based on its data type.
This code is helpful when you specifically want to check the data type and perform different actions based on the type. It can be particularly useful when you have multiple types to handle, and you want to avoid using multiple `if-elif-else` statements.

**Code 2 (Using type()):**

`type()` is a built-in function in Python that returns the type of the object.
In the given code, `type(var)` is used to directly get the type of the variable var.
This code is simpler and more straightforward when all you need is to know the type of the variable. You don't have to use multiple case blocks as in the match/case statement.
However, it doesn't allow you to perform different actions based on the type directly. You would need to use `if-elif-else` or other conditional statements to handle different types separately.

**Use cases:**

Code 1 (using match/case) is useful when you want to perform different actions based on the data type of a variable, especially when you have multiple data types to handle.
Code 2 (using type()) is helpful when you only need to know the data type of the variable and don't need to perform different actions based on the type.

**Example use cases for Code 1:**

Suppose you have a function that receives different types of input and needs to handle them differently. You can use match to handle the different data types separately.
When parsing a JSON or CSV file with dynamic data types, match can help you process each data type appropriately.

**Example use cases for Code 2:**

When debugging or analyzing code, you might want to quickly check the type of a variable to understand its behavior.
When you need to write logs or reports containing information about the data types of certain variables, `type()` can be used to extract this information.